# j2me+Google map+street view

Tags: java, java-me

I had used 
http://www.jappit.com/blog/midmaps-google-maps-java-me-library/

Where i had find the path between two location.
I had done this with the help of below code:-

```
 GoogleMapsPath path = new GoogleMapsPath(); 
path.addPoint(new GoogleMapsCoordinates(41.8954656, 12.4823243)); 
path.addPoint(new GoogleMapsCoordinates(41.8934656, 12.4833243)); 
path.addPoint(new GoogleMapsCoordinates(41.8944656, 12.4843243)); path.setColor(GoogleStaticMap.COLOR_RED);
 path.setWeight(10); map.addPath(path);
 GoogleMapsPath bluePath = new
 GoogleMapsPath();
 bluePath.addPoint(new GoogleMapsCoordinates(41.8954656, 12.4823243)); bluePath.addPoint(new GoogleMapsCoordinates(41.8954656, 12.4823243)); bluePath.addPoint(new GoogleMapsCoordinates(41.8954656, 12.4823243)); bluePath.setColor(GoogleStaticMap.COLOR_BLUE);
 bluePath.setFillColor(GoogleStaticMap.COLOR_GREEN);
 bluePath.setWeight(5);
 map.addPath(bluePath);
```

The result of this i m getting is the straight line drawn on map connecting the two location.
Now i want to draw line for showing the route on street view and also to get the distance between them.

Comment: Streetview means i want the exact direction and route between that two location

Comment: how can i able to get the driving direction in above coding